# Setting up LVM and deleting partition volume

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted, lvm, fdisk

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in VMware. I recently ran out of space so I decided to add a 10GB volume. The problem is I didn't install ubuntu with lvm initially so now I am trying to do it retrospectivly. I have tried https://github.com/g2p/blocks but for some reason I wasn't able to install it on the liveCD.

Now I went back to follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpLVM-WithoutACleanInstall

I have lvm2 installed along with fdisk and GParted. But along the way I messed something up and now I have /dev/sda3 which I can't delete:

GParted error:

```
GParted 0.18.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 2.3
Delete /dev/sda3 (lvm2 pv, 1023.00 KiB) from /dev/sda  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda3  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda3
start: 39845888
end: 39847933
size: 2046 (1023.00 KiB)
delete lvm2 pv file system  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

lvm pvremove /dev/sda3

Physical Volume /dev/sda3 not found

========================================
```

[image: Gparted]

First I would like to somehow get rid of this volume. I create a 100MB `lvm2 pv` volume just as the guide said, but I don't understand how to get the OS files onto it or even what the point of it is as later on the guide tells you to create ~10gb partitions for your usr folders etc. I'm a little lost and I wish I could just do a clean install.

Edit:

When I do: `sudo fdisk /dev/sda3`
I get: `You must set cylinders.`

Edit2:

I managed to delete /dev/sda3 using the following command:
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda3 bs=1M count=2`
and then deleting it using GParted

Now I just need a way to expand `/dev/sda1` into the unallocated space

Edit3:

Managed to solve it now, just by playing around with GParted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need lvm for this.  Blow away sda3 and and sda4 to get back to your old setup, and just move sda2 to the right ( unmount sda5 first ), then you can grow sda1 into the unallocated space.

Comment: I've been trying to delete sda3 without success. Any suggestions?

Comment: @crysis405, you don't use `pvremove` to delete the partition... click on it in gparted and pick delete.

Comment: That is what I did. That is the error log from gparted which I guess was trying to remove it using pvremove.

Comment: @crysis405, in that case just use `parted` on the command line to blow it away instead of gparted.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have any logical volume in this physical volume. Try 'sudo lvdisplay'. If yes, remove any logical volume and then try to use 'vgreduce -a' to remove any empty physical volume in the volume group.

Comment: I got `No volume groups found`

Comment: Have you tried to boot the VMware in a liveCD and try to delete the partition from there [using Gparted]? Maybe the system is using the sda3.

Comment: I have. I'm getting the same error